# Decimal point lost in conversion

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains: 2.53 and I'm trying to convert this number into `decimal` type, so I did:

```
string value = "2.53";
decimal converted = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
```

but the final result is: `253`

Comment: What is the culture of your machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decimal point is different in every culture. In your culture it might be a comma. You can use `InvariantCulture` which has `dot` as decimal separator:

```
decimal converted = Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```